# Silverstripe 4 tinyMCE not working

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Just installed SS4 via composer, everything seems to be working fine on my local machine but the WYSIWYG editor doesn't seem to be working, getting a load of console errors referring to tinyMCE and the vendor.js and webpack.

I am using webpack as a compiler but can't figure out why its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Anish

[image]

webpack config:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var externalJS = require('./js/externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    externals: externalJS(debug),
    context: __dirname +"/src",
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        head: __dirname + "/src/themes/pixellabs/js/head/head.js",
        styles: __dirname + "/src/themes/pixellabs/scss/styles.scss",
        foot: __dirname + "/src/themes/pixellabs/js/foot/foot.js",
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/themes/pixellabs/js/",
        filename: "[name].min.js"
    },a
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300 // The default
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].css',
                            outputPath: '../css/'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'extract-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'imports-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)/,
                use: [
                    {loader: "url-loader"}
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: debug ? [] : [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle: false,
            sourcemap: true
        }),

    ],
};
```

Composer output:

```
composer/ca-bundle                        1.1.1              Lets you find a path to the system CA bundle, and includes a fallback to the Mozilla CA bundle.
composer/installers                       v1.5.0             A multi-framework Composer library installer
doctrine/instantiator                     1.0.5              A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
embed/embed                               v3.3.1             PHP library to retrieve page info using oembed, opengraph, etc
google/recaptcha                          1.1.3              Client library for reCAPTCHA, a free service that protect websites from spam and abuse.
guzzlehttp/psr7                           1.4.2              PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
heyday/silverstripe-responsive-images     2.0.0              Configure and send a series of image size options to the client without loading any resources until a media query can be executed.
intervention/image                        2.4.1              Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration
league/flysystem                          1.0.44             Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
m1/env                                    2.1.0              Env is a lightweight library bringing .env file parser compatibility to PHP. In short - it enables you to read .env files with PHP.
marcj/topsort                             1.1.0              High-Performance TopSort/Dependency resolving algorithm
monolog/monolog                           1.23.0             Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
myclabs/deep-copy                         1.7.0              Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nikic/php-parser                          v3.1.5             A PHP parser written in PHP
paragonie/random_compat                   v2.0.12            PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phpdocumentor/reflection-common           1.0.1              Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock         3.3.2              With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise retrieve information that is embedded in a DocBlock.
phpdocumentor/type-resolver               0.4.0             
phpspec/prophecy                          1.7.6              Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage                 4.0.8              Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.
phpunit/php-file-iterator                 1.4.5              FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template                 1.2.1              Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                         1.0.9              Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream                  1.4.12             Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                           5.7.27             The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects              3.4.4              Mock Object library for PHPUnit
psr/cache                                 1.0.1              Common interface for caching libraries
psr/container                             1.0.0              Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/http-message                          1.0.1              Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/log                                   1.0.2              Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                          1.0.1              Common interfaces for simple caching
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup        1.0.1              Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                      1.2.4              Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                            1.4.3              Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                     2.0.0              Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                        2.0.0              Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                    1.1.1              Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator               2.0.1              Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/recursion-context               2.0.0              Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations             1.0.0              Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                         2.0.1              Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
silverstripe-themes/simple                dev-master 4d546a4 The SilverStripe simple theme (default SilverStripe 3 theme)
silverstripe/admin                        1.1.0              SilverStripe admin interface
silverstripe/asset-admin                  1.1.0              Asset management for the SilverStripe CMS
silverstripe/assets                       1.1.0              SilverStripe Assets component
silverstripe/campaign-admin               1.1.0              SilverStripe campaign admin interface
silverstripe/cms                          4.1.0              The SilverStripe Content Management System
silverstripe/config                       1.0.4              SilverStripe configuration based on YAML and class statics
silverstripe/errorpage                    1.1.0              ErrorPage component for SilverStripe CMS
silverstripe/framework                    4.1.0              The SilverStripe framework
silverstripe/graphql                      1.1.0              GraphQL server for SilverStripe models and other data
silverstripe/recipe-cms                   1.1.0              SilverStripe recipe for fully featured page and asset content editing
silverstripe/recipe-core                  1.1.0              SilverStripe framework-only core recipe
silverstripe/recipe-plugin                1.2.0              Helper plugin to install SilverStripe recipes
silverstripe/redirectedurls               dev-master 042ece4 Provides a system for users to configure arbitrary redirections in the CMS
silverstripe/reports                      4.1.0              Reports module for SilverStripe CMS
silverstripe/siteconfig                   4.1.0              Site wide settings administration.
silverstripe/vendor-plugin                1.3.3              Allows vendor modules to expose directories to the webroot
silverstripe/versioned                    1.1.0              SilverStripe Versioned component
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                   v5.4.9             Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symbiote/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions 3.1.1              A collection of useful grid field components
symfony/cache                             v3.4.8             Symfony Cache component with PSR-6, PSR-16, and tags
symfony/config                            v3.4.8             Symfony Config Component
symfony/filesystem                        v3.4.8             Symfony Filesystem Component
symfony/finder                            v3.4.8             Symfony Finder Component
symfony/polyfill-apcu                     v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring                 v1.7.0             Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/translation                       v2.8.39            Symfony Translation Component
symfony/yaml                              v3.4.8             Symfony Yaml Component
undefinedoffset/sortablegridfield         2.0.4              Adds drag and drop functionality to SilverStripe 4.x's GridField
webmozart/assert                          1.3.0              Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
webonyx/graphql-php                       v0.8.0             A PHP port of GraphQL reference implementation
```

Comment: How are you compiling with webpack?

Comment: Compiling my theme file scss and JS using webpack, my webpack config file, will update the question with my webpack file

Comment: Have you customised anything to do with TinyMCE at all? Can you post the output of `composer show`?

Comment: @RobbieAverill just updated the question with my composer output, you think something might be clashing with tinyMCE? Not customised anything with tinyMCE

Answer (score 1):

Is this on windows?

If so this might be because of the web.config in: 
public\assets

Telling your server to redirect all non listed extensions to -> 404 
Which does not include .js aka the tinyMce file will give a 404.

Solution: include the .js extension.

Comment: I'm running on Mac, just looked the web.config and .js extension is already there as allowed, not sure what else it could be?